# Is there a circuit that can create dispersion?

Tags: filter, signal-processing, phase-shift

I'm wondering if there's a circuit that would create dispersion effects. Essentially, I'd like to create a circuit which can do the following:

- Spread out a high frequency pulse. For example, put in a dirac delta function and get out a signal that looks like a gaussian distribution.
- Leave lower frequency signals relatively unchanged (no dispersion).

This might also be called a frequency-dependent phase shifter. Or a circuit which has constant group delay up to a particular "cutoff" frequency after which the dispersion effects kick in and group delay becomes non-constant.

I have a feeling there's a circuit topology that is commonly used for this, and I'd just appreciate a point in the right direction. Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: Any low-pass filter will spread out an impulsive input. If it has a gaussian response, it will spread an impulse input into a gaussian shaped pulse.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! This wasn't part of the question, but suppose I also need the amplitude of the pulse to remain unchanged (i.e., not reduced due to a low pass filter), would I just place a high-pass filter with gain before the low pass filter?

Comment: When you talk about a delta function input, you need to be careful what you mean about the amplitude.

Comment: Can you clarify if you are referring to dispersion in frequency or in time? Dispersion is commonly referred to any phenomenon that results in a propagation delay that depends on frequency (so filters with non-linear phase are "dispersive"). Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: That's right, I'm referring to dispersion in time. High frequencies will have a different time delay than low frequencies.

Comment: all pass filter (LC or RC) may be a time delay  or linear phase over certain decade range of f and fixed amplitude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on exactly what you want, you might be able to do that with a high order lowpass filter.

Both Chebychev and Butterworth filter types are criticised for their dispersion (non-linear phase, aka non-flat group delay) in the upper half of their passband, as the frequency approaches cutoff, precisely the behaviour you are looking for.

Bessel and Gaussian filters are designed to minimise this 'problem'. Elliptic filters use stopband zeroes to achieve high slope, so have less dispersion in the top part of the passband, so avoid these as well.

There are plenty of on-line filter design resources, for both active (RCopamp) and passive (LC) filters. However few if any will allow you to design for dispersion, as this is usually an unwanted feature. Choose a high order (5 to 10), Butterworth if you don't want to experiment with other parameters, Chebychev if you do, and design it with as low a passband as will accommodate your signal, and see what you get.

Comment: Any filter that is not Bessel will not have constant group delay in the passband, even if it may seem so, even Butterworth. Also, Bessel filters, as shown in the frequency response, have non-constant group delay after fc (or above, depending on the order) and, as per OP's comment, this contributes to different temporal dispertion. This complies with OP's points. All other filters that are not Gaussian will cause ripples in the impulse response, which will no longer fit OP's gaussian distribution, effect still visible in the 8th order Bessel, but much attenuated in the 16th order.

Answer (score 1):

What you say makes me think of a Gaussian filter (for the Gaussian distribution output), or a Bessel (for constant group delay until fc). However, the Bessel filter, given a high enough order, will converge towards a Gaussian, but that will happen only after many stages. If your requirements are not that high, an 8th order Bessel will give you a fairly good temporal response, which can be made with a quad opamp; a 16th order will be even better. Here's an attempt at simulating a "distribution" Dirac input, and the responses of 8th and 16th order Bessel filters (non frequency scaled):

[image: Bessel]

Also, what @ThePhoton says is true, the Dirac function is quite a peculiar one. The way I modeled it is [like a distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), but it's physically impossible.

For reference, here's how the frequency responses of the two filters look like, in terms of magnitude and group delay:

[image: freq]